# Игра "Угадай цифру"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте. 
Помогите решить задачи по `Ruby` (ну и если можно объяснить как и что).
Немного пропустил занятия по начальному программированию в университете.
Теперь нагоняю) 
Заранее спасибо!)
Не могу решить следующие задачи (делаю ошибку в коде):

1.Нужно сделать игру "Угадай цифру".
Выглядит должна приметивненько, примерно вот так:

```
Я думаю, что числа 0 до 10 Попробуйте угадать его!
Ваш ответ: **1**
К сожалению, это не оно.
Попробуйте еще раз: **0**
К сожалению, это опять не то.
Попробуйте еще раз: **2**
Конец игры. Мой номер был: **3**
*или*
Поздравляю. Это мой номер
```

ну и код:

```
    puts "Я думаю, что числа 0 до 10 Попробуйте угадать его!"
    cislo = gets.to_i
    puts "Ваш ответ:" + cislo.to_s
    x = rand(10) 
    if (x == cislo) then
    puts "Поздравляю. Это мой номер"
    elsif (x !=cislo) then
    puts "К сожалению, это не оно. \nПопробуйте еще раз:"
    cislo = gets.to_i
    elsif (x !=cislo) then
    puts "К сожалению, это опять не то. \nПопробуйте еще раз:"
    cislo = gets.to_i
    else 
    puts "Конец игры. Мой номер был:" + cislo.to_s
    end
```

и еще задача:
Если ответы будут на три вопроса будут:

```
1.**да**
2.**да** или **нет**
3.**да**
```

Ответ: **Следует повторить материал.**

Если ответы будут на три вопроса будут:

```
1.**да**
2.**нет**
3.**нет**
```

Ответ: **Следует срочно начинать повторять!**

Если ответы будут на три вопроса будут:

```
1.**да** или **нет**
2.**нет**
3.**нет**
```

Ответ: **Удачи тебе!)**

В остальных случаях:

Ответ: **Релакс.**

Код:

```
puts "вопрос 1 (да или нет)"
test = gets.strip
puts "вопрос 2 (да или нет)"
test_2 = gets.strip
puts "вопрос 3 (да или нет)"
can = gets.strip
if (test == yes && test_2 == yes && can == yes) || (test == yes && test_2 == no && can == yes) then
puts "Следует повторить материал"
elsif (test == yes && test_2 == no) && (can == no) then
puts "Следует срочно начинать повторять!"
elsif
(test == yes && test_2 == no && can == no) || (test == no && test_2 == no && can == no) then
puts "Удачи тебе!"
else
puts "Релакс."
end
```

Comment: Изучите циклы в Ruby и оберните часть кода в цикл. Тогда получится вводить число несколько раз.

Comment: Спасибо большое.
Но именно без цикла требуется.
Т.к цикл у нас будет отдельной темой.

Comment: rdoc puts gets loop

Comment: решилась вторая задача!)
оказалось нужно было сделать так например:
test == "yes" 
и т.д
И все получилось!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать elsif в первой задаче необходимо по условию? Я тоже начинающий, но мне кажется, что проверка с помощью elsif подходит, если заранее можно указать непротиворечивые варианты для проверки (как в учебниках - x>y, x<y, x=y). Если же какие-то действия должны происходить последовательно в зависимости от результатов проверки, то - без циклов и case - нужна или последовательность if и else, или вложенные if и else.
А у вас получается, что первый же elsif возвращает true (при ошибке с первой попытки) - значит, можно закрывать условие и не проверять остальные elsif.

Вот вариант, который работает:

```
    x = rand(10)
    puts "Угадайте число"
    puts x # Это чит для тестирования :-)

    number1 = gets.to_i

    if x == number1
    puts "Да, это #{x}!"

        else
        puts "Ещё раз!"
        number2 = gets.to_i

            if x == number2
            puts "Конечно, #{x}!"

                else
                puts "Упс"
                number3 = gets.to_i

                    if x == number3
                    puts "Вот и #{x}"

                    else
                    puts "Неудачник, я загадал #{x}"

                    end

            end

    end
```

Comment: Здравствуйте.
Спасибо вам большое за ответ.
Сейчас уже поздно, завтра протестирую и уверен все у меня получится!)
Осталась только вторая задача)
Надеюсь успею добраться до её решения раньше, чем здесь ответят.

Comment: Здравствуйте.Отлично!получилось решить первую задачу!)Elsif использовать не обязательно.Просто опираясь на if else elsif end (на самые базовые) еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот опять, из-за таких как Вы я и не играю в азартные игры:

Первая ошибка: сначала вы просите угадать число, и только после ответа загадываете его. Грр..

```
puts "Ваш ответ:" + cislo.to_s
x = rand(10)
```

Во-вторых, кириллица латинскими буквами - вообще амба, cislo - не кисло, но без улыбки читать нереально, используйте синтетические обороты:

```
number
value    
answer
a
joeroe
input
...
```

но не

```
cislo :)
```